# am using Gnu/Linux Deepin 15 and am suffering from the login loop. I can't get to the desktop!

Tags: deepin

Once I type the password the  system loads for a bit and then brings me back to the login form

Comment: what user are you using to login?

Comment: The root user , am using deepin 15 , found soulutions to the same problem but for other Linux distributions , they didn't work for me

Comment: There is no such thing as Linux 15 (Latest version is 4.16 and that is the unstable bleeding edge), so I corrected title. Linux is a kernel, it is used with the Gnu/Linux operating system.

Comment: My bad,  I already corrected that in my comment if u have noticed, now please can we focus on the problem!

Comment: try another user, it might be the case the root login is locked within an X session deepin is debian based an I remmember suck behaviour in debian